# Update DateTime variable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

In my C# application I declared `private DateTime _time = DateTime.UtcNow;`. I updated this in one of my methods as follows:

```
public void MessageReceived(int value)
{
    if (value == 2)
    {
        _time = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

This caused an issue when I run my application. after some investigation I found that DateTime is immutable so my method created a new instance of the variable rather than updating it to the current DateTime. How can I update it in this way? I can see that I can add a timespan to the existing method but I don't know how this can be done in the way I want to use it.

**Additional Information**

Here is my full class(logging added for demonstration):

```
public class Health : IHealth
{
    private readonly IConfig _config;
    private readonly ILogger<Health> _logger;

    private DateTime _time = DateTime.UtcNow;
    private readonly TimeSpan _timespan;

    public bool IsHealthy
    {
        get
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("IsHealthy DateTime.UtcNow: " + DateTime.UtcNow + " _time: " + _time + " _time.Add(_timespan):" + _time.Add(_timespan));
            return (_time.Add(_timespan) > DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
    }

    public Health([NotNull] IConfig healthOptions, ILogger<Health> logger)
    {
        _config = healthOptions ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(healthOptions));
        _timespan = _config.HealthTimespan;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void MessageReceived(int value)
    {
        if (value == 2)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("OnMessage DateTime.UtcNow: " + DateTime.UtcNow + " _time before: " + _time);
            _time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
}
```

`MessageReceived` is called each time a message is received and `IsHealthy` is called by a user operation. _time is updating in the `MessageReceived` method but remains at the initialized value in the `IsHealthy` whereas I would need it to match whatever the current value it is set to in `MessageReceived`.

Here's a snippet of the log output from a recent run:

> 2020-12-09 07:48:46.155Z INFO APP=2227 COMP=3790 [15] OnMessage DateTime.UtcNow: 09/12/2020 07:48:46 _time before: 09/12/2020 07:48:46 - Logger=Cdi.Mdp.FeedHandler.HealthChecks.HealthHandler,Level=INFO,ThreadId=15,
> 2020-12-09 07:48:46.181Z INFO APP=2227 COMP=3790 [17] IsHealthy DateTime.UtcNow: 09/12/2020 07:48:46 _time: 09/12/2020 07:47:52 _time.Add(_timespan):09/12/2020 07:48:22 - Logger=Cdi.Mdp.FeedHandler.HealthChecks.HealthHandler,Level=INFO,ThreadId=17,

`09/12/2020 07:47:52` is what `_time` was initialized to. The last message as received at `09/12/2020 07:48:46` and `OnMessage` was executed and `_time` set to `09/12/2020 07:48:46`. `IsHealthy` was also executed at this time but the second log line shows `_time` having the original value.

Comment: Do you want an constantly updating datetime (like a clock?) or do you want a timestamp of the current datetime? May I also ask where `value == 2` stands for?

Comment: Yes, `DateTime` is immutable, but you've declared `_time` as a writable field, so it should be overwritten when you assign to it. What's the issue?

Comment: I am keen to see how you `_time` is not changing because you declared it right

Comment: This has nothing to do with immutability. Do you want the time elapsed since the last call? `var elapsed = DateTime.Now - _time; _time = DateTimw.Now;`. This breaks at DST changes.

Comment: The provided code works fine. If you think it’s immutable, I’m sure the error is in how you use _time and I guess you buffer it or don't update the visualization or something like that. Try to reproduce it in a new program and you will see the error is not in the provided code.

Comment: _"Here's a snippet"_ - explain what we see here and what you expect to see.

Comment: I'm suspecting you'd need to make a "custom" time provider class, which would be registered as a singleton in DI. It looks like this is part of some ASP.NET stack or something, so the DateTime value will be "per-call".

An absolutely uglier but probably working solution is to make the _time field static.

I'd recommend the time provider, it usually helps with testing (mocking time :) )

Comment: Log snippet explained in question.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea I'll look into the time provider class.

Comment: I just mean a class that has a private _time field, a LastCheckedAt property returning that value, and a method/property that sets the _time to DateTime.UtcNow and returns it.  I'd make the properties/methods part of an interface. Then you'd register the implementation in whatever DI you are using as Singleton. You can check the static solution if you want something quick, but don't leave it like that in anything "production"